# При клике на кнопку заменять одно содержимое на другое JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется кнопка "Купить", при нажатии на нее, кнопка должна пропадать, а на ее месте появляться картинка "Крестик" и некоторый текст. При повторном нажатии на крестик появляется кнопка "Купить".
Подскажите как такое реализовать на JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#buy').on('click', function() {

 if ($(this).hasClass('delete')) {
  $(this).removeClass('delete').text('Buy');
 } else {
  $(this).addClass('delete').text('Delete');

 }
});
```

```html
<button id="buy">Купить</button> 


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Как-то так подойдет? На класс delete можешь вешать крестик и кастомизировать для красоты все сам